# Collect 8 bytes to char in C programming

Tags: c

I have a .txt file contains only `0` and `1` like data.
All I need to do is loop through the file, collecting 8 bits in an unsigned char by using the `<<` operator to move each bit up into place, and then write each assembled byte to ASCII.

```
bit_files *tmp;
tmp = (bit_files *)malloc(sizeof(bit_files));
char a;
char byte;
FILE *first_file,*final_file;

first_file=fopen("file1","rb");
final_file=fopen("file2","wb");

tmp->bitCount = 0;

while (a=fgetc(first_file)!=EOF){
    byte=tmp->bitBuffer<<=a;
    tmp->bitCount++;
    if (tmp->bitCount==8){
        fputc(byte,final_file);
        tmp->bitBuffer=0;
        tmp->bitCount=0;
    }
}
fclose(first_file);
fclose(final_file);
```

Comment: Please  format your code.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in

byte=tmp->bitBuffer<<=a;

You are overwriting you byte-value from the previouse bit...
try something like this instead:

Byte = Byte | (tmp->bitBuffer<<=a);